# Not able to get blur effect

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift3, uivisualeffectview, uiblureffect

I'm using UIVisual Effect view in storyBorad. I just set four constraints(top, bottom, left, right) to that view. but it looks some black colour view behind.

source code:

```
import UIKit

class SignOutViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var signouTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var desc1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var desc2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var cancelButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var sureButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var alertView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var seperatorView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonsSuperView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        prepareAlertView()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        alertView.layer.cornerRadius = alertView.frame.height * 0.05

    }

    private func prepareAlertView() -> Void{
        signouTitle.text = "Sign Out"
        desc1.text = "Do you really want to sign out"
        desc2.text = "from this account"
        signouTitle.textColor = UIColor(red: 1 / 255, green: 170 / 255, blue: 112 / 255, alpha: 1)
        desc1.textColor = UIColor(red: 195 / 255, green: 195 / 255, blue: 195 / 255, alpha: 1)
        desc2.textColor = UIColor(red: 195 / 255, green: 195 / 255, blue: 195 / 255, alpha: 1)
        cancelButton.setAttributedTitle(NSAttributedString(string: "Cancel", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.getProximaNovaSemibold(size: 16), NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]), for: .normal)
        sureButton.setAttributedTitle(NSAttributedString(string: "Sure", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.getProximaNovaSemibold(size: 16), NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]), for: .normal)
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.65)
        buttonsSuperView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1 / 255, green: 170 / 255, blue: 112 / 255, alpha: 1)
        alertView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 36 / 255, green: 36 / 255, blue: 40 / 255, alpha: 1)
    }

    @IBAction func cancelTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func sureTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    }

}
```

I added UIVisual effectView Programatically. i need visualEffect as -1 th position in viewHierarchy. but it responds as same..

Comment: Provide the code that you have written

Comment: @Praveen source code was added to the post..

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.dark)
let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
blurEffectView.frame = view.bounds
blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. but it's not woking too.I update the post take look into that...

Comment: i saw your Screenshot u can do it with uiimage for this you have to make a image with top left circle cut and Alpha ~0.8 and take UIView then take UIImageView as subclass of UIView and put your image in UIImageView then make your popup OK or Cancel and finally you can HIde and Show Your UIView.

Answer (score 0):

I faced exactly the same issue. What I did was I just used a new storyboard and presented it modally using the settings in screenshot. The blur effect then works perfectly instead of showing the black screen. You can also translate that into code if you want to do it programatically.

**Note: These settings are for the segue.**

[image]